# Ajax Call to Retrieve oData from REST API

Tags: ajax, rest, odata

I am trying to use Ajax to get data back from an oData REST API. The Ajax looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:52139/odata/WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS?key=10064450", datatype: 'json',
            success: function (oResult)
            {
                alert("good");
                $('.accountNumber').append(data.accountNumber);
                $('.civicaddress').append(data.civicaddress);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert('bad');
            }
        });
    });
```

The URL is called just fine, but then I always get the alert 'bad', so the call is throwing an error. The url is returning:

{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:52139/odata/$metadata#WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS/$entity","@odata.type":"#Values.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","accountNumber":10064450,"rowNumber":0,"civicaddress":"123 Fake St"}

So how do I get the accountNumber and civicaddress from the ajax call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested the solution was to add the following in my web.config for the REST service:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```